# Get Address from latitude and longitude using geopy pandas

Tags: python, pandas, geopy

I have an excel file containing multiple latitude and longitude and I need state, district, and city against in excel. Can anyone help me with this? (Read from excel and insert into excel)

Sample excel data is like below

[image]

I appreciate any help. Any recommended resources for mapping coordinates are greatly appreciated too. thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried google location service with API key but it is returning empty data

Answer (score 0):

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="geoapiExercises")
df = pd.read_excel('latlong.xlsx') # Your excel file location
result = []
for index in df.index:
    result.append(geolocator.reverse(f"{df.iloc[index,0]}"+","+f"{df.iloc[index,1]}")[0].split(','))
```

This may helps as it stores the result in a list of list but I am not sure how to get State, District and City informations from result as lengths of results are not same.

Comment: Its giving this just for 10 record geopy.exc.GeocoderTimedOut: Service timed out